# Python: Writing and Reading from a text file using URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, url, urllib

I have two Problems:

**First**, when I print the URL it Prints the html code of this URL (I only need to Print the content of the text file that is linked on the URL and this is my code:

```
import urllib
url="The Text File URL"
file = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
for line in file:
    decoded_line = line.decode("utf-8")
    print(decoded_line)
```

and **Finally**, I need to Write to this text file using the same URL.

Comment: What format is the text file?

Comment: U could try using `requests`: `import requests

response = requests.get("The Text File URL") data = response.text`

Comment: @pupspulver
Thank U for help but it does not work it still return the html code of the url page

Comment: can u send me the URL to test it?

Comment: @pupspulver
Ofcourse this is the URL:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ILKfsDVS2KD1Q92vY-a9wGp6xUbQlvBj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please tell me what if anything happens 
@pupspulver

Comment: of couse :), thx for the link. Perhaps you could use the google drive REST API to get the contents of a file

Comment: @pupspulver Wow, I didn't know that can you give me an example of how to print the content of this URL text file using Google drive REST API?

Comment: an alternative is to download the file, (and that's a lot easier). But to use the API is a cleaner way

Comment: @ sukan to make the usage of the API easier, u could use the `PyDrive` python package.

Comment: but I think it is not possible for every person using my app to download the file from google drive right?

Comment: it is possible, but that's not a nice practice

Comment: @pupspulver I search a lot it works and thank U soo much but still a small issue is that before he write to google drive he open in my computer a web page to choose the account in each time, I need to authorize automatically

Comment: @pupspulver I search in pydrive and google developer console

Comment: that's the only problem. PyDrive opens up a client and u have to authenticate with you google account.